Is a two way anova appropriate here?
Hello I am currently working on our undergrad thesis about the effect of the combination of FA and CCR to the strength of soil. We have 3 concentrations for FA and 3 for CCR, this is still excluding the control with 0% FA and 0% CCR. We have 10 total treatments including the control. I would just  like to ask if a two way anova is appropriate? I'm sorry I have very surface level statistics knowledge. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

From your question, it would seem you have no data on FA (or CCR) levels alone? Ie, the only data with no FA or no CCR is the control? Otherwise you would have either 9, or 16 treatments? Can you confirm?

Thanks for responding. Yes, we don't have data on FA and CCR alone. We have a total of 9 mixed samples (from 3 FA concentrations x 3 CCR concentrations) plus the control.

Short answer; yes, you can use a 2-way ANOVA. You have 2 factors, 3 levels each. Of course, you need to confirm the basic assumptions of 2-way ANOVA (normality of residuals, homoscedasticity wrt fit).
But... (yes, there is a but) the issue is what to do with the control. To include or not to include? You do not have a true factorial ANOVA; for this, you should have had 16 treatments (the 3 levels and 0%). Nor do you have a "pure" fractional factorial design. Your control is not even included in the sampling space you tested in trhe experiment: your control is at (0,0), while you tested somewhere in the strictly positive (non-null) quadrant. Therefore I would lean towards not including it in the ANOVA; you can still use 2-sample comparisons to the control (with appropriate multiple comparison corrections, e.g. Sidak), but including it in the model may confuse the model, because the control is not in the sampling space. Of course, you can always try both ways; if you get similar answers, then there is no issue. Otherwise, I would believe the ANOVA which did not include it.

Can you elaborate on what makes an FFD "pure"? I understand that fractional just means testing a subset of all possible combinations. I am struggling to understand how the ANOVA would be confused.

A valid fractional factorial design would select half the cases (so 8 in your case), but not randomly; it would strategically confound certain factors (at the cost of no longer being able to test the interactions), to minimize sample size. The faction select would be statistically identical to all the other possible fractions. But that is not what you did, with your 10 out of 16. The regression model will try to fit that "outlier" datapoint, which is the only one of its kind. Regression can be severely influenced by outliers.
